# PHP- Regex to match words with more than two letters

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to explode a string into a word array, the condition is that a word is considered as such only if it has two or more letters, what I have is the following, but words with a single letter are still being considered as match:

```
$input_string = "I have a cake inside my fridge";

$string_array = preg_split("/[^\w{2,}]*([\s]+([^\w{2,}])*|$)/", $input_string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

But I'm still getting the words "I" and "a", why it isn't working?

Comment: Alt without regex.. i.e less confusing, explode with array_filter: https://3v4l.org/kdPgh

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yeah, thank you, but it has to be done with a regex pattern :/

Comment: What is the exact output you expect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because the pattern `[^\w{2,}]*([\s]+([^\w{2,}])*|$)` [matches only spaces](https://regex101.com/r/8MM5hd/1), and then you split on those spaces resulting in an array with all the words. This is due to `\s` which matches a whitespace char, and using the negated character class `[^\w{2,}]` which also matches whitespace chars.

If you want to use split, you also have to match the single word characters so that they are not part of the result.

---

If you must use split, you can match either a single word character surrounded by optional horizontal whitespace characters to remove those as well, or match 1+ horizontal whitespace characters.

```
\h*\b\w\b\h*|\h+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oq0khU/1)

For example

```
$input_string = "I have a cake inside my fridge";
$string_array = preg_split("/\h*\b\w\b\h*|\h+/", $input_string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($string_array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => have
    [1] => cake
    [2] => inside
    [3] => my
    [4] => fridge
)
```

---

If you want to match all strings that consist of at least 2 characters, you could also use `\S{2,}` with [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to capture all "words" having 2 or more letters, then just use `preg_match_all` here:

```
$input_string = "I have a cake inside my fridge";
preg_match_all("/\b\w{2,}\b/", $input_string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => have
    [1] => cake
    [2] => inside
    [3] => my
    [4] => fridge
)
```